# How to avoid same node.js packages installing several times when they are used as dependencies by different modules?

Tags: node.js, npm

I noticed that npm installs the same node.js packages several times when they are required by different modules.

Is there an option to switch this off and to have one repo for all the packages?

I looked but did not find anything on this...

Comment: I think it's by default. Node js seems always have dependencies in node_modules.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the default behaviour of NPM since version 3.  Quoting the [changelog of that version](https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/v3.0.0/CHANGELOG.md#flat-flat-flat):

> Your dependencies will now be installed maximally flat. Insofar as is possible, all of your dependencies, and their dependencies, and THEIR dependencies will be installed in your project's `node_modules` folder with no nesting. **You'll only see modules nested underneath one another when two (or more) modules have conflicting dependencies.**

As you can see, if you have modules which have conflicting dependencies (i.e. require different versions of the same dependency), multiple versions of such dependencies will be installed, and this cannot be avoided.

If you suspect that your `node_modules` directory somehow contains duplicates, you can use the command `npm dedupe` ([docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/dedupe.html)) to find these and reduce the duplication, leaving only one instance of each duplicate.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how npm defines what is conflicting and what is not? E.g. if one package requires the module 2.4.1 and the other one is 2.4.5 the latest one will be installed (and only one) as it's not breaking, while if there's 2.6.3 required by the other package, then both will be installed as they might be breaking, is that how it works? Thanks!

Comment: It depends on how the dependencies are declared. For example, if one package requires a module with version **exactly** 2.4.1 and another requires **exactly** 2.4.5, this will be considered incompatible and NPM will install both. However, if one package requires `^2.4.1` and another requires exactly 2.6.3, then 2.6.3 will be compatible with both packages.

Comment: You can read more about NPM's dependency range notation [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver#advanced-range-syntax)